# SharePoint Foundation 2010 Misaligned Date Picker Control on Upgraded WSS 3.0 Sites

Tags: calendar, sharepoint-foundation, datepicker

We recently upgraded our WSS 3.0 site to SharePoint Foundation 2010. Following the upgrade we've noticed that the date picker control does not align correctly on some of the old WSS 3.0 sites as shown in the picture below:

[image: Misaligned Date Picker Control]

It's odd, because some of the old WSS 3.0 sites and any new SharePoint Foundation 2010 site renders the control correctly as shown in this picture:

[image: Correct Alignment for Date Picker Control]

Can anyone tell me why some of the sites are not rendering this control in the correct location?

Can anyone tell me how I can correct this problem?

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that you have some kind of customizations on the sites with the misaligned control. Check for custom CSS or JavaScripts loaded on those sites. An easy way to do it is to open up Internet Explorer Developer toolbar and inspect the HTML element and then check where the element inherits its CSS styles from. Compare a correctly aligned element with an misaligned.

Comment: I checked the CSS for these pages and the only differences are in colors and images. I don't see any positional directives that are different between in the CSS between the two pages. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the javascript for datepicker is customized. Please check in the newform.apsx whether there is a customized javascript for datepicker (OOB js file is datepicker.js). If there is customized javascript just search for a function called  clickDatePickerHelper and comment it. This should solve the problem

Comment: Thanks for the input but your suggestion doesn't seem to fit. I can't find any customized javascript (only reference is to datepicker.js) and I also can't find any references to "clickDatePickerHelper". Any other suggestions?